# Scikit-Learn Linear Regression how to get coefficient's respective features?

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression, feature-selection

I'm trying to perform feature selection by evaluating my regressions coefficient outputs, and select the features with the highest magnitude coefficients. The problem is, I don't know how to get the respective features, as only coefficients are returned form the coef._ attribute. The documentation says:

> Estimated coefficients for the linear regression problem. If multiple
>   targets are passed during the     fit (y 2D), this is a 2D array of
>   shape (n_targets, n_features), while if only one target is passed,
>   this is a 1D array of length n_features.

I am passing into my regression.fit(A,B), where A is a 2-D array, with tfidf value for each feature in a document. Example format:

```
         "feature1"   "feature2"
"Doc1"    .44          .22
"Doc2"    .11          .6
"Doc3"    .22          .2
```

B are my target values for the data, which are just numbers 1-100 associated with each document:

```
"Doc1"    50
"Doc2"    11
"Doc3"    99
```

Using regression.coef_, I get a list of coefficients, but not their corresponding features! How can I get the features? I'm guessing I need to modfy the structure of my B targets, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 34):

What I found to work was:

X = your independent variables

```
coefficients = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(X.columns),pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(logistic.coef_))], axis = 1)
```

The assumption you stated: that the order of regression.coef_ is the same as in the TRAIN set holds true in my experiences. (works with the underlying data and also checks out with correlations between X and y)

Comment: I think you can just do pd.DataFrame(zip(X.columns, logistic.coef_))

Answer (score 15):

You can do that by creating a data frame:

```
cdf = pd.DataFrame(regression.coef_, X.columns, columns=['Coefficients'])
print(cdf)
```

Comment: regression.coef_ is now returned as a dataframe so to do this 
cdf = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(X.columns),pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(regression.coef_))], axis = 1)

Answer (score 10):

```
coefficients = pd.DataFrame({"Feature":X.columns,"Coefficients":np.transpose(logistic.coef_)})
```

Comment: This does not work for me. *Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional*

Comment: @ytu try coefficients = pd.DataFrame({"Feature":X.columns,"Coefficients":np.transpose(logistic.coef_[0, )})

Answer (score 9):

I suppose you are working on some feature selection task. Well using `regression.coef_` does get the corresponding coefficients to the features, i.e. `regression.coef_[0]` corresponds to "feature1" and `regression.coef_[1]` corresponds to "feature2". This should be what you desire.

Well I in its turn recommend tree model from sklearn, which could also be used for feature selection. To be specific, check out [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html).

Comment: This is true as long as regression.coef_ returns coefficinet values in the same order. Thanks.

Comment: The ExtraTreesClassifier is actually very interesting, but it seems there is no way to retrieve the actual features which it picked after the model has been fit?

Comment: @jeffrey Yes, but I always select feature by `clf.feature_importances_ ` to retrieve the importance ranking of features. Well intuitively it is just like the coefficients of the Linear Model, isn't it?

Comment: Well, if you use a feature selection method like a CountVectorizer(), it has a method get_feature_names(). Then you can map get_feature_names() to .coef_ (i think they are in order, I'm not sure). However, you cannot do this with the tree.

Answer (score 5):

## Coefficients and features in zip

```
print(list(zip(X_train.columns.tolist(),logreg.coef_[0])))
```

## Coefficients and features in DataFrame

```
pd.DataFrame({"Feature":X_train.columns.tolist(),"Coefficients":logreg.coef_[0]})
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is the easiest and most intuitive way:

```
pd.DataFrame(logisticRegr.coef_, columns=x_train.columns)
```

or the same but transposing index and columns

```
pd.DataFrame(logisticRegr.coef_, columns=x_train.columns).T
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your train data X variable is 'df_X' then you can map into a dictionary and feed into pandas dataframe to get the mapping:

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(df_X.columns,model.coef_[0])),index=[0]).T
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting them in a series with the data columns names as index:

```py
coeffs = pd.Series(model.coef_[0], index=X.columns.values)
coeffs.sort_values(ascending = False)
```